# a sudden increase on loss rates during the training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data

I am trying to train a ResNet50 on a dataset with 16800 images of size(480,270) divided into 100 class. 
At the beginning of the training, the loss was decreasing, then it starts to encrease

A am using the following compiling settings to my model:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here are the loss and accuracy rates for the first epochs [image: loss]
[image: accuracy]

I wonder if this is an overfitting aspect although the large dataset? and how could I do to help loss to decrease again? should I decrease the learning rate or wait for some more epochs or other solutions?

Comment: I don't think it's overfitting since the loss on training data is increasing. I would try to decrease the learning rate first and see what happens.

Comment: @zfabian okay, I will try to reduce the learning rate and see how it will perform